# How do I veto a specific UNIX path with Samba? (Match one directory with a specific name, but NOT any others)

Tags: samba

So I recently learned about the `veto files` option for Samba, and I want to use it to hide just *one* directory that matches a given name.

Example: I have two directories with the following UNIX paths:

- /storage/data/nextcloud
- /storage/users/trwnh/nextcloud

I want to veto the first one, but *not* the second one.

Options I've tried:

- `veto files = /storage/data/nextcloud` (didn't work, so I read the man page a bit more closely and discovered that the / is an OR separator and not a path separator)
- `veto files = /storagedatanextcloud` (my first assumption was that I should simply remove the path separators -- it must be a bit late, IDK why I thought that would work)
- `veto files = /nextcloud/` (works, but hides both directories instead of just the first)

At this point I'm stuck, and I'm not even sure if the functionality I want is implemented within Samba, so I turn to the Internet to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

smb.conf(5) implies that you can not veto specific paths, only file (and dir) names, let them be anywhere.

```
       veto files (S)

       This is a list of files and directories that are neither visible nor accessible. Each entry in the
       list must be separated by a ´/´, which allows spaces to be included in the entry. ´*´ and ´?´ can
       be used to specify multiple files or directories as in DOS wildcards.

       Each entry must be a unix path, not a DOS path and must not include the unix directory separator
```

So it's not what you are looking for, given that you can not change neither `nextcloud` directory's name.

There are some options:

my assumption is that you access samba with the same user as your system user, so you can not revoke r/x bits only from samba user without affecting your linux user's permissions.

1. run samba in a separate mount namespace, in which you over-mount the directory you want to hide. see `unshare(1)` and `mount --bind`, may need to tune samba init scripts a bit.
2. bind-mount the whole /storage to somewhere else, eg. /smb/storage, and over-mount /smb/storage/users/trwnh/nextcloud. and point the samba share to /smb/storage. this way you don't need separate mount namespace.
3. put /storage/data and /storage/users in separate shares.
4. make a samba vfs module which's only job is to hide the unwanted directory.

Comment: I think I might have to go with (3) and just live with the [storage] share not showing user nextcloud folders, since the [storage_users_trwnh] share would show it, right? Only downside being I have to mount two shares on each client instead of one. And I suppose also that I can't name any directory or file "nextcloud" without it similarly disappearing.